# how to subtract the two files in linux

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, grep

I have two files like below:

file1

```
"Connect"    CONNECT_ID="12"
"Connect"    CONNECT_ID="11"
"Connect"    CONNECT_ID="122"
"Connect"    CONNECT_ID="109"
```

file2

```
"Quit"    CONNECT_ID="12"
"Quit"    CONNECT_ID="11"
```

The file contents are not exactly same but similar to above and the number of records are minimum 100,000.

Now i want to get the result as show below into **file1** (means the final result should be there in file1)

```
"Connect"    CONNECT_ID="122"
"Connect"    CONNECT_ID="109"
```

I have used a while loop something like below:

```
awk {'print $2'} file2 | sed "s/CONNECTION_ID=//g" > sample.txt

while read actual; do

    grep -w -v $actual file1 > file1_tmp
    mv -f file1_tmp file1

done < sample.txt
```

Here I have adjusted my code according to example. So it may or may not work.

My problem is the loop is repeating for more than 1 hour to complete the process.

So can any one suggest me how to achieve the same with any other ways like using `diff` or `comm` or `sed` or `awk` or any other linux command which will run faster?

Here mainly I want to eliminate this big typical `while` loop.

Comment: Are the connect_id unique numbers or are there duplicates?

Comment: I don't think "lack" is obvious, nor is ["lakh" / "lac"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) (which I assume you are actually intending) outside South-East Asia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most UNIX tools are line based and as you don't have whole line matches that means `grep`, `comm` and `diff` are out the window. To extract field based information like you want `awk` is perfect:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}!($2 in a)' file2 file1
"Connect"    CONNECT_ID="122"
"Connect"    CONNECT_ID="109"
```

To store the results back to `file1` you'll need to redict the output to a temporary file and then move the file into `file1` like so:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}!($2 in a)' file2 file1 > tmp && mv tmp file1
```

**Explanation:**

The `awk` variable `NR` increments for every record read, that is each line in every file. The `FNR` variable increments for every record but gets reset for every file.

```
NR==FNR    # This condition is only true when reading file1
a[$2]      # Add the second field in file1 into array as a lookup table
next       # Get the next line in file1 (skips any following blocks)
!($2 in a) # We are now looking at file2 if the second field not in the look up
           # array execute the default block i.e print the line
```

To modify this command you just need to change the fields that matched. In your real case if you want to match field 1 from `file1` with field 4 from `file2` then you would do:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($4 in a)' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|\S+\s+(\S+)|/\1/d|' file2 | sed -f - -i file1
```

Comment: Please explain me how it works so that i can change this according to my requirement.

Comment: @vidyadhar this solution changes file2 into a sed script which inturn is run against file1. To see the script remove from the pipe onwards. The first sed command removes the first non-spaces string i.e. the "Quit" string and uses the remainder as a pattern to delete a line in file1.

Comment: it is nice....Will you please tel me if file1 contain records like <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-16T12:15:59" NAME="Connect" CONNECTION_ID="6386761" STATUS="0" USER="zemddbuser" PRIV_USER="zemddbuser" OS_LOGIN="" PROXY_USER="" HOST="" IP="66.161.124.157" DB="CUST_ZETAMAILDEMO_DB"/> and FILE2 contains records like  <AUDIT_RECORD TIMESTAMP="2013-08-16T12:15:59" NAME="Quit" CONNECTION_ID="6386759" STATUS="0"/> then how to use the sed

Comment: @vidyadhar determine the unique key in file2 and use it as the pattern to match in file1 be it `TIMESTAMP` or `CONNECTION_ID` or `...`

Answer (score 2):

The tool best suited to this job is `join(1)`. It joins two files based on values in a given column of each file. Normally it just outputs the lines that match across the two files, but it also has a mode to output the lines from one of the files that do not match the other file.

`join` requires that the files be sorted on the field(s) you are joining on, so either pre-sort the files, or use process substitution (a `bash` feature - as in the example below) to do it on the one command line:

```
$ join -j 2 -v 1 -o "1.1 1.2" <(sort -k2,2 file1) <(sort -k2,2 file2)
"Connect" CONNECT_ID="122"
"Connect" CONNECT_ID="109"
```

`-j 2` says to join the files on the second field for both files.

`-v 1` says to only output fields from file 1 that do not match any in file 2

`-o "1.1 1.2"` says to order the output with the first field of file 1 (`1.1`) followed by the second field of file 1 (`1.2`). Without this, `join` will output the join column first followed by the remaining columns.

Comment: A big caveat is that `join` requires sorted input.  If the sizes of the files are too big to fit into memory, it cannot be avoided, but if you can keep everything in core, avoiding the sort will typically be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to analyze file2 at fist, and append all ID which have appered  to a cache(eg. memory)
Than scan file1 line by line to adjust whether the ID in the cache.

python code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

p = re.compile(r'CONNECT_ID="(.*)"')

quit_ids = set([])

for line in open('file2'):
    m = p.search(line)
    if m:
        quit_ids.add(m.group(1))


output = open('output_file', 'w')
for line in open('file1'):
    m = p.search(line)
    if m and m.group(1) not in quit_ids:
        output.write(line)
output.close()
```

Comment: Here I am using Shell scripting .... If possible please help me how to write the code in shell scripting..

Answer (score 0):

The main bottleneck is not really the `while` loop, but the fact that you rewrite the output file thousands of times.

In your particular case, you might be able to get away with just this:

```
cut -f2 file2 | grep -Fwvf - file1 >tmp
mv tmp file1
```

(I don't think the `-w` option to `grep` is useful here, but since you had it in your example, I retained it.)

This presupposes that `file2` is tab-delimited; if not, the `awk '{ print $2 }' file2` you had there is fine.

Comment: Here file2 contents are compared to file1 and unmatched records from file1 are printed right...